# Raspbian Swapping Log into RAM

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to set up a Raspberry Pi for 24/7 Mode.I am Using `Raspbian` with a GUI. In this context, I want to swap the Directory /var/log into the RAM.

I tried to ad the following entry to `fstab` to reach

**my Requirement:**

```
none /var/log tmpfs size=10M,noatime 00
```

How can i ensure, that the directory was added to the RAM?
Did i forgot something ro reach my purpose? 
Do you guys have any ideas how i can swap a directory to RAM? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the usefull log2ram tool (https://github.com/azlux/log2ram).

It will allow you to mount the /var/log folder into RAM and archive your logs in the folder /var/hdd.log once a day or whenever you want by modifying cron script. This feature is very useful for reading your logs after a stop of your RPI!